# WKWebView open in new viewcontroller

Tags: html, swift, xcode, web, wkwebview

I am facing a problem, in an early fase of my app. I am trying to open at link from WkWebview in a new viewcontroller, with another WKWebview. The reason is, that i am having some buttons in the second viewcontroller. Is this possible in Xcode/Swift?

Regards
Frederik

Comment: Post your code you had tried.

Comment: I have not tried anything yet - i am pretty blank.. But here is my code for the WKWebView:

Comment: let myURL = URL(string: "mydomain.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        mainFront.load(myRequest)

Comment: What does "open in new viewcontroller" mean? Pushing a new controller, presenting it modal? How is your current controller looking like and how do you intercept the click on link? There are a lot of unknowns in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate
. Inside the *decidepolicyfor*-method, you can analyze the request url and do some custom stuff, like opening it somewhere else.

You obviously have to implement a delegate somewhere, either as an additional class or inside your Viewcontroller.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I will check up on it, and eventually mark your answer, if it works. Thanks ;)